# Why does it take more time when I fetch an info from more than two tables?

Tags: sql

It's regarding SQL Devloper. Suppose I have three tables Table1, Table2 and Table3. When I run below query

```
select * from Table1 where coustomer_id in (select custmoer_id from Table2 where city='Pune');
```

Above query fetches the result in less than 2 seconds.
But when I try to fetch the info from more than two tables it takes too much time. For example:

```
select * from Table3 where building_name in (select building_name from Table1 where customer_id in (select customer_id from Table2 where city='Pune'));
```

So in this case it takse more time in comparison to above query. 
Why does it take so much time and is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on `building_name` in Table3 and Table1?  You should also look into `Join` for simplicity.

Comment: Without knowing the DB schema and how big the dataset your are querying, at least for these tables, it's hard to say. However, when doing nested selects like this your first place to look is composite indexes for those columns.

Comment: @Siyal: an index on `building_name` in `Table2` will not improve the speed of this query unless it's part of a composite index in the form `(customer_id, building_name)`.

Comment: At least one of your sub-selects (and probably both) can be replaced by a JOIN, which will increase speed considerably if there are proper indexes.

Comment: @KenWhite: Are you aware of any modern database engine that produces significantly different response times to queries expressed as a `JOIN` or a sub-query assuming the two queries yield the same results?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know for sure without seeing the structure of your tables (and it's not clear what "more time" means).  But the most likely reasons are:

- `Table3` does not have an index on `building_name`.
- There are a lot more records in `Table3` than `Table1`.
- `Table3` has many more columns than `Table1`.